# Why is 1 000 000 not equal to 1000000.toString("N", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))

Tags: c#, unit-testing, formatting, tostring, cultureinfo

I writing some unit tests around string conversions and currency.

I'm testing that the string is returned in the format that I expect it, given the CultureInfo the method is passed.

```
 public string GetOverspendAmount(double _amount, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
 {
    return amount.ToString("N", cultureInfo);
 }
```

I'm unit testing this bit of code with the following call -

```
double amount = 1000000;
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR", false);

GetOverspendAmount(amount, ci).Should().Be("1 000 000");
```

but the test fails. The expected and actual look identical but when put into an ascii converter the following results are shown

```
Expected - 1 000 000
49 32 48 48 48 32 48 48 48

Actual - 1 000 000
049 194 160 048 048 048 194 160 048 048 048
```

They're not normal spaces, but I'd like to know what they are, and why they aren't just normal spaces?

Comment: Why not use the [**Memory** window in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2019) and look at the actual byte values?

Comment: [it's not 32 but 160](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3FHODU) aka [non breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

Comment: The actual string looks more like "1 000 000,00" than "1 000 000".

Comment: Good spot, I've corrected it in the question. That was an error from me trying to simplify the question from my code

Comment: You can see this special space character if you go to Control Panel -> Region -> Set Format to "French - France" -> Additional Settings -> Look at the setting for "Digit grouping symbol". It's a special non-breaking space (and you can select other characters from the drop-list).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space is a no-break space (UTF-8 194 160) and not the regular space (UTF-8 32).

https://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec

The no-break space makes a difference in formats like HTML, as it wouldn't allow automatic line break after it. It also doesn't allow multiple spaces collapsing into a single one.